# Access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy - LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, rest-api, rest, cors

I'm having the following error once I try to do a POST in an outside link of my Salesforce org,
[image]

So, I've already added this URL to the "CSP Trusted Sites"  and the "Remote Site Settings", but nothing is working now, just gave me this error.

This is the fetch used for this request:

```
        fetch(endpoint, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        })
```

and the first criteria of the method:

```
        const endpoint = 'https://ab.us.cd.com/fg/hi/jk/lm';
        const headers = {
            'APIKEY': 'a'
        };
```

I appreciate every reply here,

Thank you very much.

Comment: Beware you might be sharing your API secret.

Answer (score 1):

You should import `cors` and add all your URL in safelist.

You can try with below code

```
import cors from "cors";

const safelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
const corsOptions = {
  origin: safelist
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/03/working-with-cors-and-csp-to-call-apis-from-lwc